# Book Search: Blue-Eyed Boys with Telepathic Powers

Tags: story-identification

Call me crazy, but I've got an itch I can't scratch. I read a lot in school and one of the books I remember from Junior High (early 2000's) was a book about some children that were being experimented on in a lab. I think I recall they had powers and the boy's eyes glowed blue as he was able to read minds/move objects with his mind etc. I'm pretty sure he was trying to escape the lab and the doctors.

Comment: Do you have any idea when it was published? Did it look recently published or would it have been older?

Comment: Also what sort of setting was it? Contemporary or futuristic or whatever?

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. We recommend having a look at the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour), which contains helpful hints for using the site. As this is a story identification question, you can also have a look at this [guide](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info).

Comment: I found [a similar thread on Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/topic/show/97930-psychic-children-kidnapped-and-held-institute-trained-to-use-powers). Some possibilities that were raised there: [*Mind Trap*](https://www.amazon.com/Mind-Trap-G-Clifton-Wisler/dp/0525674640) | [*Cries of the Children*](https://books.google.co.il/books?redir_esc=y&id=G28kAgAAQBAJ&q=blue#v=onepage&q=eyes&f=false) |  [*Hear the Children Calling*](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=MuWbAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_atb#v=onepage&q=blue&f=false). *Mind Trap* has a kid with blue eyes on the cover.

Comment: Confirmation that it's the Seer is in the comments bellow the answer

Answer (score 5):

Yes, *[Mind Trap](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3201325-the-mind-trap)* is definitely the book. Thank you Mithrandir.

[image: Book Cover - Mind Trap]

> Scott's identity as a telepathic alien from another planet may be exposed when he's imprisoned in a research institute for psychic children run by a mysterious doctor.

Comment: Since you self-answered, you will be able to (and should) accept your own answer 48 hours after asking the question, or about 2 AM EST on the 20th of October, 2017.

Comment: Actually I think The Seer is the correct book, because Mind Trap is a sequel.